# grpc in k8s cannot resolve service dns name

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, grpc

i am using node js trying to run grpc in kubernetes cluster env. localy without kubernetes its working fine.the server side is listening to : `'0.0.0.0:80'` and client tries to connect via: http://recommended-upgrades-qa-int. in the kuberenets i get the following error:

```
ERROR failed to get via grpc the getRecommended Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed endpoint:http://<K8S_SERVICE_NAME>
ERROR: Recommendations fetch error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed severity=error, message=failed to get via grpc the getRecommended Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed endpoint:http://<K8S_SERVICE_NAME>
```

server side:

```
const connectionHost = this.listenHost + ':' + this.listenPort;
server.bind(connectionHost, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
logger.info(`Server running at ${connectionHost}`);
server.start();
```

client side:

```
RecommendedService = grpc.load(__dirname + '/../../node_modules/@zerto/lib-service-clients/Output/sources/recommendedClient.proto').RecommendedService;
        } catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }

        this.client = RecommendedService && new RecommendedService(grpcAddress, grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
```

manefist files:

### server side

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-side-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server-side-deployment
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server-side-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: server-side-deployment
        image: (DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH)
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: recommended-upgrades-qa-int
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
      app: server-side-deployment
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: http
```

### client side

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-side-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client-side-deployment
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client-side-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: client-side-deployment
        image: (DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH)
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: RECOMANDED_SERVICE
            value: http://recommended-upgrades-qa-int
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Is you client running in the same namespace of your server ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/):

> “Normal” (not headless) Services are assigned a DNS A record for a name of the form my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local. This resolves to the cluster IP of the Service.

Your issue here is probably sing `<service name>` while your service is in another namespace. Try using:

```
<service name>.<service namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: services are in the same namespace

Comment: also checked connection with telnet and curl and it was responding. only grpc is not working

Comment: see above in my question the client and server manifest files

Comment: Hmm it looks fine, but can you check `recommended-upgrades-qa-int:80` instead of `http://recommended-upgrades-qa-int`? Are you sure that inside of your container the networking is done correctly for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

it seems we figure it out. first the url must contain port 80 also there was an inner uncaught exception in the server service which may caused it not to work.
Thank you all